# selection gets light grey in edit mode, no selection highlight

Tags: edit-mode

earlier in edit mode I would see edges same black color, but now only outline edges are seen, and in light grey, which is so hard to see. Also, when I am trying to select edges, vertices, or faces, they don't get highlighted with orange.

I'm also not able to select any other objects in the scene than one show after switching to the object mode. Restarting did not help. The only way I can select objects in the object mode is in the right hand side object list.

### blender file

[image]

version 2.93.2

### object mode

[image: object]

### edit mode

[image: edit]

this "feature" changed suddenly and I'm trying to figure how to revert it.

Comment: It's probably a bug, I highly recommend you to update your blender to 2.93.4 because is the most recent stable version

Comment: @Emir that didn't help

Comment: can you share the blend file? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: @MartyFouts please see the update

Comment: Your second image show that you are using the Layout workspace. (The very top header shows a horizontal list starting with  File, Edit, Render ........... followed by a list of the available workspaces, Layout, Modelling Sculpting etc ). Change to the Modelling workspace and you should be good to go :)

Comment: You have "Mesh" off inside the view object types, that's under the icon with an eye and an arrow, but that's only for the blend file that you share, your images doesn't appear to have it off, but you could try there.

Answer (score 2):

You disabled Mesh selections, reenable them by clicking on: [image] then: [image]

[image]

Comment: I now see Emir's comment, if it's disabled in the file, but not disabled on your screenshot, it's perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 1):

[image: show overlays]

You should check show overlays, at the right top of the 3D viewport.
And check in the object types visibility the arrow for the mesh
[image]

Comment: that didn't help

Answer (score -1):

Change the Workspace from Layout to Modelling and then the selecting should be working as before.

[image]